# Dr Java Compiler Issue I think

Tags: java, compiler-errors, drjava

I've been getting this error in a popup. I can compile but when I try to run it gives me "Current document is out of sync with the Interactions Pane and should be recompiled!"

Please tell me how to fix this and how to get my dr.java up and running so that I can compile and test my codes.

Below is a thorough detail of all the errors.

> Pop-up error: { 7 errors occured! Please submit a bug report
> containing the information below and an account of the actions that
> caused the bug (if known) to http://sourceforge.net/projects/drjava.
> You may wish to save all your work and restart DrJava.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.FilePane$SortableListModel.getElementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.getSelectedValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame.getSaveFile(MainFrame.java:4662)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame$8.getFile(MainFrame.java:412)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.AbstractGlobalModel$ConcreteOpenDefDoc.saveFileAs(AbstractGlobalModel.java:3223)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.AbstractGlobalModel$ConcreteOpenDefDoc.saveFile(AbstractGlobalModel.java:3178)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.AbstractGlobalModel.saveAllFilesHelper(AbstractGlobalModel.java:1558)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.AbstractGlobalModel.saveAllFiles(AbstractGlobalModel.java:1535)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame._saveAll(MainFrame.java:5324)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame$ModelListener._saveAllBeforeProceeding(MainFrame.java:9757)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame$ModelListener.saveBeforeCompile(MainFrame.java:9686)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.GlobalEventNotifier.saveBeforeCompile(GlobalEventNotifier.java:428)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.CompilerEventNotifier.saveBeforeCompile(CompilerEventNotifier.java:98)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.DefaultCompilerModel._prepareForCompile(DefaultCompilerModel.java:222)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.DefaultCompilerModel.compileAll(DefaultCompilerModel.java:163)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame._compileAll(MainFrame.java:5749)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame.access$5300(MainFrame.java:129)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame$55.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:970)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

System Properties:
DrJava Version drjava-20190813-220051
DrJava Build Time 20190813-220051

drjava.debug.port = 59754
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin
java.vm.version = 25.144-b01
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator = ;
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
user.country = US
user.script =
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level =
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir = <anonymized user.dir>
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_144-b01
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\endorsed
os.arch = amd64
java.io.tmpdir = <anonymized user.home>\AppData\Local\Temp\
line.separator = "\u000d\u000a"
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
user.variant =
os.name = Windows 10
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;<anonymized user.home>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons = true
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version = 52.0
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version = 10.0
user.home = <anonymized user.home>
user.timezone = America/New_York
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding = Cp1252
java.specification.version = 1.8
java.class.path = <anonymized user.dir>\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar
user.name = <anonymized user.name>
java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
sun.java.command = <anonymized user.dir>\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
sun.arch.data.model = 64
user.language = en
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.version = 1.8.0_144
java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\classes
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
file.separator = \
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian = little
java.rmi.server.hostname = 127.0.0.1
sun.desktop = windows
sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
```

DrJava configuration file
In resource bundle edu.rice.cs.drjava.config.options:
nothing

In shadowed configuration:

```
extra.classpath = G:\\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\\becker.jar;G:\\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\\becker.jar
key.delete.next = [shift DELETE]
key.delete.previous = [shift BACK_SPACE]
window.height = 744
window.width = 1382
window.x = -8
window.y = -8
window.state = 6
last.dir = G:\\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)
last.interactions.dir = G:\\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)
tabbedpanes.state = 683 384 700 400
new.version.notification = all release versions
new.version.notification.last = 1614097735431


Used memory: about 52.96 megabytes
Free memory: about 38.54 megabytes
Total memory: about 91.50 megabytes
Total memory can expand to: about 1.65 gigabytes

Number of processors/cores: 4

Compiler Discovery Log:
}
```

I can't Uninstall or Update. I borrowed my laptop from the school and I don't have much control over what I uninstall or update. I tried downloading a newer version to overwrite the old version but for some reason that did not work not to talk about the fact that I barely have less than 1 GB of space.

Apart from that, my laptop forced me to restart for some updates or something and now when I open Dr.Java I do not get that error anymore but the compiling and running issue still persists. This is keeping me from running programs and testing them.

More details on the issue, I did some troubleshooting including changing the code so that all it does is create a plain class and the main method, but it still would compile but then ask to be recompiled when I try to run it.

Also, I get this in the console tab at the bottom now:

```
"Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
Compiler is using classPath = '[G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns), G:\ICS4U0- Computer Science(Mr. Burns)\becker.jar, G:\Downloads\drjava-beta-20190813-220051.jar]'; bootClassPath = 'null'
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath"
```

Comment: Did you delete and re-post that question?

Comment: @dan1st could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I thought I saw another question with a similar title and similar content earlier today but it might be my mistake.

Comment: Oh, that was me from another account. Apparently, someone did not get the question (how do I fix this) and voted the question to be closed while I was asleep. I did edit this to be a bit clearer now. I tried using an older version and it is currently working but if anyone has a fix to this, still let me know.

Comment: Did you ever consider that the reason people closed your question is because it needs focus?

Comment: Let's have a [mcve].